# Is it possible to print raw command with Ansible for debugging

Tags: debugging, ansible

I have a Ansible raw instruction, and I would like to know if it is possible to print it after jinja2 interpretation ( with `{{ org }}` replaced by the value)

```
---
- name: Install chaincode
  raw: "docker exec 'cli.{{ org }}.{{ global_domain }}' bash -c 'export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.{{ org }}.{{ global_domain }}:7051 && peer chaincode install -n {{ item.chaincode.name }} -v {{ item.chaincode.version }} -p {% if global_chaincode_lang != 'golang' %} /opt/gopath/src/{{ item.chaincode.name }} {% else %} {{ item.chaincode.name }} {% endif %} -l {{ global_chaincode_lang }}'"
```

I tried to add `-vvv` after the ansible-playbook instruction, but it didn't work

How should i do it ???

Comment: what do you want to print? (first: shrink your example, second: show what you want to see).

Comment: docker exec 'cli.myorg.mydomain' ...

Comment: "it didn't work" ... because it did what instead?

Comment: It showed me other info, but not what I was expecting --> the raw command with the variables explicited

Comment: That is _for sure_ not my experience: `- raw: echo {{ ansible_version }}` run with `-vvv` produces `<localhost> EXEC echo {'string': '2.10.6', 'full': '2.10.6', 'major': 2, 'minor': 10, 'revision': 6}`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer,

Based on [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html):

you can do:

```
- name: print the string with interpreted variables
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: docker exec 'cli.{{ org }}.{{ global_domain }}' bash -c 'export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.{{ org }}.{{ global_domain }}:7051 && peer chaincode install -n {{ item.chaincode.name }} -v {{ item.chaincode.version }} -p {% if global_chaincode_lang != 'golang' %} /opt/gopath/src/{{ item.chaincode.name }} {% else %} {{ item.chaincode.name }} {% endif %} -l {{ global_chaincode_lang }}'
```